# javax.vecmath returns wrong value for quaternion calculation (where reffernce implementation works correct)

Tags: java, math

I have the following code to extract the heading from a Quaternion.

```
import javax.vecmath.Matrix3d;
import javax.vecmath.Quat4d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3d;

public static double toHeading(Quat4d q) {
        Vector3d v = new Vector3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        Matrix3d m = new Matrix3d();
        m.set(q);
        m.transform(v);
        double headingRad = Math.atan2(v.y, v.x);
        return headingRad;
    }
```

In general it work as it should, but only for small angle values I observed a strange behavior. When I input the following Quaternion `x=0.00666661728238647, y=0.0, z=0.0, w=0.9999777778600933` then it should return `0.7622087155227671` degree, but it returns `0`. When I input the values [here](http://quaternions.online/) the online calculator returns the correct value. To me this looks like an bug. Can someone verify this ? Am I doing something wrong here ?

I use the following Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quaternion is

```
q = w + i*x+j*y+k*z
= cos(phi) + i*sin(phi)  where  phi = 0.006666666664992743
```

The vector you are going to transform is

```
v = i
```

The transformation is

```
v = q * v * q.conj() = i
```

and returns thus the unchanged vector. The pair its first coordinates is `(v.x,v.y) = ( 1,0)` which has angle zero. Thus the java library returns the correct result.

---

What you probably want and entered into the web formular is to have the quaternion be

```
q = cos(phi) + k*sin(phi)
```

so that the axis of rotation is the z axis. The rotation formula then gives

```
v = q*v*q.conj() 
= (cos(phi) + k*sin(phi))^2*i
= (cos(2*phi)+k*sin(2*phi)) *i 
= i*cos(2*phi)+j*sin(2*phi)
```

Here `(v.x, vy) = (cos(2*phi), sin(2*phi))` which has the angle `2*phi=0.013333333329985486=0.76394372664928°`

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanaition helped solve the problem! I use a conversion `EulerAngle` -> `AxisAngle` -> `Quaternion` and the AxisAngle part caused the problem the code was `double norm = x * x + y * y + z * z;
if (norm < 0.001) {
 x = 1;
 y = z = 0;
} else {...}` now I changed it to be z axis and everything works as it should